# Using the CSS @layer rule in my Angular project

Tags: css, angular, dom, css-layer

I want to use the CSS @layer rule in my Angular project.

The priority order of @layers depends on their declaration order (the last one declared takes precedence). However, Angular automatically manages the order of component imports in the DOM. This can interfere with my layer declarations because I cannot control the CSS priority order (in the components stylesheets).

If someone can help me, I would like to know:

- How can I use the @layer CSS rule in an Angular project with many components?
- Especially, is there a way to declare the order of my layers in a special stylesheet that would be imported before all components (to have full control over CSS priority order)?

I couldn't find any info on the internet and had difficulty finding documentation on how angular imports components into the dom

Comment: If you need to manage something like this you either need to write your styles in the main CSS file for the application, or turn off view encapsulation on every component where you want the styles to affect the global scope

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.